# Random behaviour while reading from subprocess stdout in a thread

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am writing a script that to start a process and check's its stdout (while it's being run, not at the end of execution).

The obvious choice seemed to have a thread that will be blocked reading lines from the process stdout.

I have tested it with WSL2 bash using:

```sh
python __main__.py 'echo ok'
```

The outcome is random, resulting in one of the following cases:

- Execution terminated without any output
- "ok" printed as expected
- "ok" printed follow by a 'ValueError: readline of closed file' exception

Any idea on what might be the problem ?

The code:

```py
import argparse
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import threading


class ReadlineThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, proc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._proc = proc

    def run(self):
        while self._proc.poll() is None:
            line = self._proc.stdout.readline()
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
            sys.stdout.flush()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('command', nargs='+', help='bar help')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with Popen(args.command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) as proc:
        stdout_thread = ReadlineThread(proc)
        stdout_thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `Popen`'s `with` block can return (closing the file) while the thread is still running (using the file). Add `stdout_thread.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a thread, it becomes part of the parent process. The parent process is the thread that runs your main function. In your main function, you call `stdout_thread.start()`, which begins the process of starting a thread and then immediately returns. Aftfer that, there is no more code in your main function, which results in python shutting down the main process. Since your thread is part of the main process, it will be taken down when the main process terminates. Meanwhile, the thread you've started up is still being created.

Here we have what is called a race condition. Your thread is starting while simultaneously the process it belongs to is shutting down. If your thread manages to start up and complete its work before the process terminates, you get your expected result. If the process terminates before the thread has started, you get no output. In the third situation, the process closes its stdout before the thread has finished reading it, resulting in an error.

To fix this, in your main function you should wait for your spawned thread to finish, which could be achieved by calling `stdout_thread.join()`.